# How to convert files to Base64 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, filereader

I have registration for in React where I need to upload files to the server. Those files needs to be Base64 encoded.

The function to encode it is as follows:

```
getBase64(file) {
        let document = "";
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            document = reader.result;
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };

        return document;
    }
```

And function to handle click on form's next button is as follow:

```
handleNextButtonClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = {domainId: this.props.user[0].domainId, name: steps.stepThree, values: this.state.files};

    let idCard = this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "ID_CARD")[0].values.file;
    let statuses = this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "STATUTES")[0].values.file;
    let blankLetterHead = this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "LETTER_HEAD")[0].values.file;
    let companyPhoto = this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "COMPANY_PICTURE")[0].values.file;


    let idCardBase64 = this.getBase64(idCard);
    let statusesBase64 = this.getBase64(statuses);
    let blankLetterHeadBase64 = this.getBase64(blankLetterHead);
    let companyPhotoBase64 = this.getBase64(companyPhoto);
}
```

If I console log for example the first one `this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "ID_CARD")[0].values.file;` I get

[image]

Everything seems ok, but I'm getting error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

Any idea how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

```
let idCardBase64 = idCard ? this.getBase64(idCard) : "";
let statusesBase64 = statuses ? this.getBase64(statuses) : "";
let blankLetterHeadBase64 = blankLetterHead ? this.getBase64(blankLetterHead) : "";
let companyPhotoBase64 = companyPhoto ? this.getBase64(companyPhoto) : "";
```

I changed it. And in this case exists only `idCard`. Now I do not get any errors but `idCardBase64` is `""` and not Base64 encoded.

Comment: File reading code looks proper. Can you verify all 4 files exists?

Comment: @AjaySuvarna I updated my question.

Comment: Might be something with how you store/filter your data in/from state? Can you show a state example? For example `statuses = this.state.files.filter(file => file.file_type === "STATUTES")`, is this supposed to be STATUSES or STATUTES?

Comment: file reading is asynchronous, so what you return from getBase64 function is empty string.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

file reading is asynchronous. so use callback or promise to solve your problem.

```
let idCardBase64 = '';
this.getBase64(idCard, (result) => {
     idCardBase64 = result;
});
```

and use callback to return the data which you get.

```
getBase64(file, cb) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        cb(reader.result)
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}
```

Comment: How can we console.log base64 result which we can get from reader?

Comment: @HappyPatel you can use a console.log in idCardBase64, after the getBase64 method is executed.

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can use this React component [React File Base64](https://github.com/BosNaufal/react-file-base64)

Check the [demo](https://rawgit.com/BosNaufal/react-file-base64/master/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-base64 it makes things a lot simpler.

Use the below as an input field in a form to handle the encoding for you.

My code looks like the below for reference.

```
<FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({base64}) => setListingData({ ...listingData, selectedFile: base64})}/>
```

Comment: Easy solution, this package works for me.
<FileBase
          type="file"
          multiple={false}
          onDone={({ base64 }) => setSingleFile({ selectedFile: base64 })}
          onChange={(e) => e.target.files[0]}
        />

Answer (score 2):

Extending from the accepted answer, a little cleaner syntax

```
async function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = reject
  })
}

// usage
await getBase64(file) // `file` your img file
  .then(res => console.log(res)) // `res` base64 of img file
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```