# issue sending uploaded image file from reactJS frontend to django python backend (file sending as undefined)

Tags: reactjs, django, image, file-upload

I am trying to send various data types from user input on the reactJS frontend to the Django python backend and getting an error where the text string sends but the image file does not.

here is where I am sending the image and caption

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        console.log('Image: ', this.props.fileInput);
        console.log('Image type: ', typeof this.props.fileInput);
        console.log('Image is a File: ', this.props.fileInput instanceof File);

        formData.append('file', this.props.fileInput);
        // formData.append('file', this.props.file);  
        formData.append('caption', this.state.caption);
        for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
          console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }
        
        const response = await axios.post(API_URL, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('Image uploaded successfully');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

on the caption component and for the image component I did

```
  updateImage = async (imageId, caption) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        console.log('File:', this.state.file); 
        console.log('Caption:', caption); 

        formData.append('file', this.state.file);  
        formData.append('caption', caption);

        for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }

        const response = await axios.post(API_URL, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('Image processed successfully');
            const currentState = this.state;
            const newState = {...currentState};
            newState.elements[imageId].URL = response.data.image_url;
            this.setState(newState);

            return response.data.image_url; 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
...
...
return(
...
            {this.state.newElement &&
                <Caption 
                    file={this.state.file} 
                    imageId={this.state.newElement.id} 
                    updateCaption={this.updateImage} 
                />
            }
            </div>            
        );
    }
}

export default Image;
```

please let me know if there is something clearly wrong or what you would try to resolve this, I appreciate any guidance or help as this is the final issue I am trying to resolve!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your files to base64 string. Then send your request as json objects. In the django app, parse the base64 string to your desired file and use it.
I have saved myself tons of hours and headaches by using base64 strings.

Keep in mind that base64 makes your files slightly larger.

Comment: thats a great idea, do you have any resources or pointers you can recommend? I would appreciate any help as I am new to JS

Comment: This could help you regarding the conversion of files to base64 in reactjs: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176280/how-to-convert-files-to-base64-in-react) and use built-in libraries and File objects to handle decoding base64 in django