# How do I set the image data of an IonImg element to be the contents of a variable of type "Buffer"?

Tags: reactjs, image, ionic-framework, buffer, src

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18.  I have this type defined

```
interface Card {
    ...
  frontImg: Buffer;
  frontImgAltText: string;
    ...
}
```

In my component, how do I set the image for an IonImg element to be the image data from the above Buffer?  I tried this

```
 const base64Data = card.frontImg.toString("base64");
  const dataUri = `data:image/png;base64,${base64Data}`;

      <IonImg src={dataUri} alt="My Image" />
```

but nothing appears despite the fact that I see the binary content when I output the vars to console.log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176280/how-to-convert-files-to-base64-in-react

Comment: so the answer in your case should be : `let dataUri = ''; this.getBase64(card.frontImg, (result) => {
     dataUri= result;
}); dataUri  =  `data:image/png;base64,${dataUri}`;` then `<IonImg src={dataUri} alt="My Image" />`

Comment: Could you upload the `base64Data` content somewhere?

Comment: I'm just going to return base64 encoded data from the server.  Converting it on the front end is too heavy of a lift and maybe not the right architectural approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To display an image from a Buffer in an IonImg component in an Ionic React application, you can convert the Buffer to a base64 data URI and use it as the src attribute of the IonImg component. However, Ionic React doesn't support using a data URI directly as the src attribute.

To overcome this limitation, you can create a custom component that handles rendering the image from the Buffer data. Here's an example:

```
import { IonImg } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';

interface CardProps {
  card: Card;
}

const CardComponent: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ card }) => {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const base64Data = Buffer.from(card.frontImg).toString('base64');
    const dataUri = `data:image/png;base64,${base64Data}`;
    setImageSrc(dataUri);
  }, [card.frontImg]);

  return <IonImg src={imageSrc} alt={card.frontImgAltText} />;
};

export default CardComponent;
```

In this example, we create a CardComponent that takes a card object as a prop. Inside the component, we use React.useState and React.useEffect to convert the frontImg Buffer to a base64 data URI and set it as the src value for the IonImg component. By using React.useEffect with a dependency array that includes card.frontImg, we ensure the image is re-rendered whenever the frontImg data changes.

You can then use this CardComponent in your main component as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import CardComponent from './CardComponent';

const MainComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const card: Card = {
    // ... card properties
    frontImg: bufferData, // Replace with your specific Buffer data
    frontImgAltText: 'My Image Alt Text',
    // ... other card properties
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... other content */}
      <CardComponent card={card} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainComponent;
```

Comment: THis fails with the runtime error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined" on the line "const base64Data = Buffer.from(card.frontImg).toString('base64');"